# Hash of a complex structure

Tags: c, hash

I'd like to know a relatively simple way to generate the hash of a complex C structure (which form a graph, in my case). By "simple" I mean, if possible, without having to go through all the nodes it forms. My goal would be, afterwards, to check if two structures are identical thanks to their hash, but also to sort them in an orderly way.

There are functions and algorithms for numbers or strings for instance, but I don't know a good way to do it for a structure. What would you recommend?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree. However, while identity is fairly straightforward to define and implement, defining an order is something only you can do (unless you give a lot more details here).

Comment: If you do not “go through” a node of a structure when computing its hash, then the hash cannot include any information about the node. Then it is impossible for the hash to indicate whether or not two structures are identical with respect to such a node. You will need to explain the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The Git version control system has a hashing system like you describe. A Git repository is a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Each commit is a node.

Each commit has an ID. The ID is a hash. It hashes the content of the node, plus the hashes of all its connections.

For example, if you make a commit it will have an ID which is the hash (a sha256 checksum) of its contents. We'll call that commit A. If you make another commit on top of A, its ID will be a hash of the commit's contents plus A's hash. And so on.

```
A hash(A's content)
^
|
B hash(hash(B's content) + A's hash)
^
|
C hash(hash(C's content) + B's hash)
```

If you have a merge, where a single merge commit has two connections, it will use both node's hashes.

```
 C
 ^
 |\
 D E
 ^ ^
 |/
 F hash(hash(F's contents) + D's hash + E's hash)
```

Finally, Git also stores the nodes in a hash keyed by their commit ID for O(1) node lookup by ID.

F's hash depends on D and E's hashes which depend on C's hash which depends on B's hash which depends on A's hash. F's hash depends on the content of the entire repository. If any of the past commits change, whether by content or connection, F's hash will be invalid.

This is how Git is able to compare repositories for changes so quickly. It only needs to compare the commit IDs of the tip of each branch to know if there's a difference, then work backwards until it finds a common commit ID. It uses the graph to walk the commit history backwards, and the hash to look if there are commit IDs in common.

---

This technique only works because Git's graph is a DAG. Connections only ever point one way (Directed) and there are no loops (Acyclic). Maybe this applies to your situation, or maybe you an adapt the technique.